# Input de tipo file para obtener la duracion de un video

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Buen dia; 
Es posible obtener la durecion de un video al capturarlo con input type="file"

```
<input type="file" class="" id="mivideo" name="mivideo>
```

ya sea con javaScript o jQuery o PHP

Comment: te puedo ayudar con un ejemplo pero con la etiqueta video al cargar el contenido, dime es eso lo que necesitas?

Comment: talvez te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285056/get-video-duration-when-input-a-video-file

Comment: @AlfredoPaz lo que necesito es que el vídeo subido por medio del input type="file" pueda verificar que no pase de 3 minutos

Comment: @JuanDaniel gracias lo reviso

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `duration` para obtener la duración de un video:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myVideo").duration;
```

Se obtiene la duración en segundos, así que en tu caso deberías evaluar que no pase de 180 segundos (3 minutos).

Te anexo un ejemplo:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("video").duration;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="http://html5facil.com/demos/videos/big_buck_bunny.webm"  type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
    <source src="http://html5facil.com/demos/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1,mp4a"'>
  </video>
<p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Obtener duración</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero te ayude.